# Apache2- need multiple projects with same domain that use different path after domain name

Tags: configuration, apache2, virtualhost

I have 2 completely different projects I would like to host from the same domain name "mysimpledomainname.com"     with ip address xx.xx.xxx.xx (not local)

The 2 projects are located at
Project 1)   /var/www/html/project1
Project 2)  /var/www/html/project2

I would like to have the 2 projects resolve like this

### Project 1

mysimpledomainname.com

### project 2

mysimpledomainname.com/project2

I DO NOT want to use subdomain names.  This is for a project on my public server, not my local machine, so I don't think updating the host file will help me.

I already have the first project loading from mysimpledomainname.com (it's already working).

In the directory sites-available I have the conf file mysimpledomainname.com.conf with values:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin myemail@gmail.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/project1
        <Directory /var/www/html/project1/>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride All
                Require all granted
                RewriteEngine On
        </Directory>
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

I think I need to have 2 different conf files set up in order to do this, but after searching around I have not been able to find a solution.
Can anyone help me with this?  Rather than giving a short answer can you post exactly what I would need for the 2 different conf files?

Thanks,

David

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can have only 1 `VirtualHost` directive as this is defined per FQDN and you want to use only `mysimpledomainname.com`.

Your config for *Project1* is OK. You just need to make available another directory under path `/project2`. To do this, you need to use the [`Alias`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html#alias) directive.

So your final config should be something like this (of course you can have separate `Directory` configurations for each subdir if you want):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin myemail@gmail.com
        DocumentRoot    /var/www/html/project1
        Alias /project2 /var/www/html/project2
        <Directory /var/www/html/>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride All
                Require all granted
                RewriteEngine On
        </Directory>
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Thanks so much for you answer.  I had tried using Alias before, but I had the Directory configuration pointing to my DocumentRoot.  Your configuration works.

Comment: Thank you for this. I have been searching for a potential solution since yesterday. Most tutorials assume the use of subdomains.